# Non functioning default policy in SailsJS

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I'm trying to implement the basic Passport integration in SailsJS. In my policies.js file, I have the default settings that every tutorial mentions.

```
'*': ['passport', 'sessionAuth'],

'auth': {
  '*': ['passport']
}
```

My issue is that going to the main page `localhost:1337/` doesn't seem to get passed through either policy. If I just set `false` there, everything still works. If I set `false` on the `auth` object for `'*'` though, I will get `Forbidden` on any `/auth/*` route. So, the policies seem to work, I just don't understand why the default catch-all doesn't. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use a controller or do you directly serve a view like in the sample homepage?

If you are serving the view directly with something similar to this:

```js
// in config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  '/': {
    view: 'homepage'
  }
}
```

then you will have to modify it and use a controller in order to te able to use policies.

Create a route to a controller instead of a view:

```js
// in config/routes.js
module.exports.routes = {
  // Delete the previous definition and declare a route
  // to a controller "index"
  'get /': 'indexController.home'
}
```

Create the controller:

```js
// in api/controllers/IndexController.js
module.exports = {
  home: function (req, res) {
    // Render the view located in "views/homepage.ejs"
    res.view('homepage');
  }
};
```

Then you will be able to manage the policies to apply to the  controller `index` in the file `config/policies.js`.